# Issue with json creation and parsing

Tags: android, json

hi am facing some kind of issue with the code . Following is my code to generate json data

```
for(int i=0; i < allEds.size(); i++){
                String edsText = allEds.get(i).getText().toString();                                           
               //spinner = allSpns.get(i);
               String spinSelected=allSpns.get(i).getSelectedItem().toString();                  
               try
                {
                   JSONObject json = new JSONObject();          
                   json.put("FieldName", edsText);
                   json.put("FieldType",spinSelected);
                   parent.accumulate("data", json);



                }
                catch (JSONException e)
                {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }                   

            }
```

It work fine and getting if i made more than one entry to json

```
correct out put
{"data":[{"FieldType":"Character","FieldName":"fffg"},{"FieldType":"Character","FieldName":"fg"]}
```

When only one entry as json it gives the following out

```
{"data":{"FieldType":"Character","FieldName":"ffg","Id":0}}
```

While parsing the second json am getting errors..Any thing wrong on my code?

code i used for parsing json

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(folderStructure);
        JSONArray data = jsonObj.getJSONArray("data");
         //ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> folderList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        for(int i=0; i<data.length(); i++)
        {

            //HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
             JSONObject obj=data.getJSONObject(i);
             String id = obj.getString("Id"); 
                String valueName = obj.getString("FieldName"); 
                String valueType = obj.getString("FieldType"); 
}
```

Comment: Its actually your parsing code that doesn't seem flexible. Put that code too

Comment: Your code is incomplete. It contains how to create json object. You need to show how to create json array too.

Comment: please show more code for generating json data..:D

Comment: I mean more code for generating json..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JSONObject parent = new JSONObject();
JSONArray jdata = new JSONArray();

    try{
         for(int i=0; i < allEds.size(); i++){
             JSONObject childObj = new JSONObject();         
             childObj .put("FieldName", allEds.get(i).getText().toString());
             childObj .put("FieldType",allSpns.get(i).getSelectedItem().toString());

             jdata .put(childObj).toString();
            }
          parent.put("data",jdata);
       }
       catch (JSONException e){
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

With only one entry, your code does not create a JSONArray. Your parsing code however always expects this array.

Answer (score 0):

In your parsing json code,

> you get data as **json array**. That's why the first one is Ok[data is
>   json array] and second one[data is json object] is not OK.

In order to avoid this, you shoud used same format for generating json data as second one too like

```
{"data":[{"FieldType":"Character","FieldName":"ffg","Id":0}]}
```